# selecting columns in awk discarding corresponding header

Tags: awk

How to properly select columns in awk after some processing. My file here:

```
cat foo

A;B;C
9;6;7
8;5;4
1;2;3
```

I want to add a first column with line numbers and then extract some columns of the result. For the example let's get the new first (line numbers) and third columns. This way:

```
 awk -F';' 'FNR==1{print "linenumber;"$0;next} {print FNR-1,$1,$3}' foo
```

gives me this unexpected output:

```
linenumber;A;B;C
1 9 7
2 8 4
3 1 3
```

but expected is (note B is now the third column as we added linenumber as first):

```
linenumber;B
1;6
2;5
3;2
```

[fixed and revised]

Comment: _line number and extract first and last columns_ is not the same as your expected output is. Please elaborate and fix the question.

Comment: You say "just for the example let's get first and third columns", show code that tries to do that and the output from that code which is what we'd expect given that code, but then you show the desired output and it doesn't contain the values from the 3rd column. Please [edit] your question so it's consistent throughout regarding whatever your requirements are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you print `$0` (the complete record) in your header? And, if you want only two columns in your output, why to you print 3 (`FNR-1`, `$1` and `$3`)? Finally, the reason why your output field separators are spaces instead of the expected `;` is simply that... you did not specify the output field separator (`OFS`). You can do this with a command line variable assignment (`OFS=\;`), as shown in the second and third versions below, but also using the `-v` option (`-v OFS=\;`) or in a `BEGIN` block (`BEGIN {OFS=";"}`) as you wish (there are differences between these 3 methods but they don't matter here).

[EDIT]: see a generic solution at the end.

If the field you want to keep is the second of the input file (the `B` column), try:

```
$ awk -F\; 'FNR==1 {print "linenumber;" $2; next} {print FNR-1 ";" $2}' foo
linenumber;B
1;6
2;5
3;2
```

or

```
$ awk -F\; 'FNR==1 {print "linenumber",$2; next} {print FNR-1,$2}' OFS=\; foo
linenumber;B
1;6
2;5
3;2
```

Note that, as long as you don't want to keep the first field of the input file (`$1`), you could as well overwrite it with the line number:

```
$ awk -F\; '{$1=FNR==1?"linenumber":FNR-1; print $1,$2}' OFS=\; foo
linenumber;B
1;6
2;5
3;2
```

Finally, here is a more generic solution to which you can pass the list of indexes of the columns of the input file you want to print (1 and 3 in this example):

```
$ awk -F\; -v cols='1;3' '
  BEGIN { OFS = ";"; n = split(cols, c); }
  { printf("%s", FNR == 1 ? "linenumber" : FNR - 1);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf("%s", OFS $(c[i]));
    printf("\n");
  }' foo
linenumber;A;C
1;9;7
2;8;4
3;1;3
```

Comment: my bad, the actual file is much larger (500 columns) so I made some mistakes writing the example here. In fact I select a lot of columns.

Answer (score 1):

To get your expected output, use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
}
{
    print (FNR==1?"linenumber":FNR-1),$(FNR==1?3:1)
}' file
```

Output:

```
linenumber;C
1;9
2;8
3;1
```

To *add a column with line number and extract first and last columns*, use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
}
{
    print (FNR==1?"linenumber":FNR-1),$1,$NF
}' file
```

Output this time:

```
linenumber;A;C
1;9;7
2;8;4
3;1;3
```